# Derivative of an integral for multiple varibles

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

I am struggling with this question;

[image]

I used the definition of $F'(x)$ and directional derivatives,$$F'(x)=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{E(x+h,x+h)-E(x,x)}{h}$$
$$=\sqrt{2}\lim_{s\to0} \frac{E(x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}s,x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}s)-E(x,x)}{s}$$$$ = \nabla E(x,y) \cdot (1,1) \bigg|_{y=x}$$
$$=\frac{\partial E}{\partial x}(x,y) \bigg|_{y=x}+\frac{\partial E}{\partial y}(x,y)\bigg|_{y=x}$$

but i was in trouble for solving $\frac{\partial E}{\partial x}(x,y) \bigg|_{y=x}$.

If I use Leibniz rule and taking x-partial derivative to $\sqrt{t^4+x^3}$ , then it is impossible to integrate with respect to $t$.

Please help me. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question explicitly ask you to use **chain rule** to find $F'(x)$. Do you know what that means?

Do you know how to find the derivative in general for
$$
G(x)=\int_{0}^{b(x)}f(x,t)\ dt,
$$
or more general 
$$
G(x)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x,t)\ dt?
$$
If you are still confused, take a look at

[Differentiation under the integral sign.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign)

Comment: thank you for your answer!